# Angular cli argumento desconocido

Tags: nodejs, angular, web, cli

tengo un proyecto que corre a base de dependencias de nosé js y con un comando de angular cli. Al instalar las dependencias no tengo problemas, pero al ejecutar el siguiente comando:

Ng serve --open

Me bota el siguiente error [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabrá porque indica que el comando --open es desconocido :(

Comment: ¿Estás seguro estás en la carpeta del proyecto? Solo obtengo [ese mensaje](https://ibb.co/ts5myg4) cuando estoy en una carpeta que no es la del proyecto.

Comment: Sip, estoy dentro de la carpeta, es por eso que ya me frustre no tengo ni la menor idea de porque me está dando este error es muy frustrante. Ya que a mis compañeros de trabajo les corre perfectamente

Comment: ¿Y con solo `ng serve` funciona? ¿Qué versión de `angular-cli` estás usando (ejecuta `ng version`)? ¿No tienes un script configurado en el `package.json` con `npm start`? ¿No puedes agregar al script la badera `--open`? Ejecuta `Get-ChildItem` y pega la salida para ver la estructura de tu directorio.
`

Comment: Si en esencia utilizamos el comando ng server --open para que se nos abra directamente en el navegador web,  la versión que tengo es la 14.0.1, si tenemos el script ejecutado, ejecutare el comando get que mencionas para ver la salida. Ya que se me hace muy raro que esto pase :(

Answer (score 1):

Intenta esto:

- Borra node_modules y package-lock.json, de la carpeta del proyecto
- Luego ejecuta `npm install`

**Recomendaciones:**
Revisa el archivo `package.json`y asegúrate de que exista la siguiente linea `"@angular/core": "14.0.1"`

Otra recomendación es validar la instalación de Angular y que esta sea de forma global `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: Hola ya logré resolver el error, usualmente suelo instalar el node js y sus complementos mediante cmd de windows probé a instalarlo desde la carpeta del proyecto y directamente desde visual studio y eso resolvió el error